# Datepicker attached to a React input component

Tags: javascript, dom, widget, reactjs, polyfills

In case of absence of native `<input type="date">` support, I'd like to polyfill all the date inputs with datepicker widgets; for example, [jQuery UI datepickers](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

See the demo [here.](http://ikr.su/h/react-period-of-stay-input/demo.html) In Google Chrome it renders native date inputs, while in Firefox (v32.0.3) the jQuery UI widgets get deployed. That's exactly where I'm having a problem. All the manual changes in the input (keyboard edits) get reflected in the datepicker widget just fine. However, the other way around, if I select a day in the widget calendar, the new value doesn't get picked up by the underlying React component. In the demo you'll notice that in Chrome, on a date selection, the other date gets auto-adjusted. That functionality is broken for datepickers in Firefox. React has no idea that values change.

Following [this advice](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html), I've added

```
componentDidMount: function(e) {
    this.getDOMNode().addEventListener(
        'change',
        function (e) { console.dir(e); }
    );
},
```

to my `DateInput` component class. However, it never gets called on widget selections. How can I make it work?

The full non-compressed source code of the demo linked above is available [here.](https://github.com/ikr/react-period-of-stay-input)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is doing everything over jQuery, and not over the DOM directly:

```
var isPolyfilled = function () {
        return (window && window.$ && window.$.datepicker);
    };

module.exports = React.createClass({
    ...

    componentDidMount: function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (isPolyfilled()) {
                window.$(this.getDOMNode()).datepicker();
                window.$(this.getDOMNode()).on('change', this.handleEdit);
            }
        }.bind(this), 500);
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function () {
        if (isPolyfilled()) {
            window.$(this.getDOMNode()).off();
        }
    }

    ...
};
```

The complete source code is [on GitHub.](https://github.com/ikr/react-period-of-stay-input)